# How to get the binary representation of the content of a DOM element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, binary, typed-arrays

Getting the string representation is quite straightforward, but I cannot find how to get the binary content (ultimately into a typed array). For example if a div has CDATA content that is binary data, rather than base64 encoded. Other similar examples exist as well, in which the contents of the div are not necessarily entirely in string format. The approach is intended to work when the document source url is file:// as well as http://, so I cannot necessarily reread the content via an XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Divs don't actually have string contents. Divs may have TextNodes that have string content.

I'm not really sure why you'd need to dump binary content into the DOM though. Can't you just keep in JavaScript?

Comment: The reason the content has a non-textual representation is to save space. Putting it in javascript wouldn't help. The binary encoding is to be be interpreted by javascript, though.